# How does the sorting by "my votes" on Area 51 works if I didn't vote on any of examples?

Tags: support, area-51

I can sort example questions by "my votes" on Area 51, but I don't get the logic of sort if I din't vote on any of examples. How are they sorted then?

Comment: It works just fine for me. Bumps all the questions I've voted on to the top of the list.

Comment: @animuson oops. I rephrased my question a little.